How to improve self-answered question
I posted and self-answered a question.  The question I posted was minimal, but I put a lot of work into the answer.  It was closed because of the rule that self-answered questions need to meet the same standards as any other question, so I improved it.
It sat there closed for several hours, so I deleted it and reposted the more complete question with the same answer:  How to build rgl in RStudio on a Mac?.
Someone objected to that, possibly for good reason:  we don't want people doing that normally to circumvent closure.
My reasoning was that the reopen queue is too full, and this would just save time for everyone.  I was accused of plagiarizing the answer from the first post.
This strikes me as a mess that could have been handled better if it had been made more obvious to everyone that it was a self-answered question.  Certainly my accuser didn't notice that the first one was self-answered as well.
A better solution than closing would have been to leave a comment on the question asking for it to be expanded, rather than voting to close it.  Or maybe I should have included the text of my answer in the question itself.

It is not relevant that a question is self-answered, as we do not have special rules for self-answered questions. And it's generally not recommended to comment and wait for a response before closing a question, that causes unnecessary delay. While it may be unfortunate that the review process for reopening takes long, that's what we have to deal with. What exactly are you asking here? Your title seems to imply you want to improve the question, but it seems fine and is open

"For several hours"? I've waited days for my incorrectly closed questions (with many upvotes and no downvotes) to be reopened.

You generally shouldn't repost closed questions. The reopen queue will take some time, but you should've waited for that.

"Or maybe I should have included the text of my answer in the question itself." Absolutely not. That would be a very good reason to downvote or possibly even closevote the question.

A self-answered question should really be asked in exactly the same way as if you weren't self-answering and were looking for someone else to answer. That's pretty much all there is to it.

" Or maybe I should have included the text of my answer in the question itself". If one does that, any other user that encounters the question should edit it to remove the answer part.


It sat there closed for several hours, so I deleted it and reposted
the more complete question with the same answer

Don't do that. If the question is closed it should be improved and not asked again. Reopening may take some time and if you have a good reason to believe it should be reopened you can always ask on Meta.

Someone objected to that, possibly for good reason: we don't want
people doing that normally to circumvent closure.

Why do you think that your case does not fall into the "normal" category? It is not going to get special treatment just because it is self answered.

My reasoning was that the reopen queue is too full, and this would just save time for everyone

Again, this would mean special treatment comparing to other posts that are going through reopen queue. Rules apply equally for everyone.

A better solution than closing would have been to leave a comment on
the question asking for it to be expanded, rather than voting to close
it

That is always an option, but if the question has issues users can vote to close immediately, without waiting for improvement. Often enough leaving question opened leads to no improvement.
When it comes to self answering there is no reason to specifically cater for such situations as it could easily lead to self answer abuse.

Or maybe I should have included the text of my answer in the question itself.

No. This would be a meta commentary which does not belong in the question itself.

Good answer but it is a little selective; at least address the plagiarism claim as well so it isn't completely one-sided.

@Gimby The plagiarism claim was just a mistake, which is not something that usually happens on self answered questions, that is why I haven't addressed that in my answer. User who commented does not have enough reputation to see deleted posts so they might have missed the fact that first question was posted by another user.
